# WampApache Service not running

Tags: windows, apache, wamp, wampserver

I am using wamp for 2 years, but now it is giving an error

> **HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.**

on running localhost and phpmyadmin.

I tried the following:

1. Restarted all services.
2. Downloaded and installed again
3. Checked that no other program was using port 80.
4. skype is not running.
5. In services wampmysqld is running but wampapache is not running.
6. Tried to run service manually and it says

   > **Windows could not start the wampapache on local computer.**

Do you have any solution for this?
The wampserver shows the status of online and its color is orange.
Before the error occurred it was green.

Comment: Usually when Apache is not running it is because there is an error in your config. Either httpd.conf has a syntax error or you are trying to load an extension that cannot be found. Look in your Apache error log  after you try to start the service and post the recent errors here and maybe we can help.

Comment: thanx i searched about it it and i found that the problem was caused by the email server i installed on my pc.

Comment: I had a similar problem because of a wrong line in **httpd.conf** (for `ErrorLog`).